# Unable to export Eclipse Plugin

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have created a plugin which adds a menu to the existing menu (Using Hello, World Command)

when i run it while testing, the runtime runtime-EclipseApplication was created and i could see the Menu and Command. But when i install it from export wizard, i couldn't see the menu.

There are no logs to debug this issue.

I already have same type of plugin (Using Hello, World Command) installed. will that cause any issues

this is the plugin.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
        name="Sample Category"
        id="CheckList.commands.category">
      </category>
      <command
        name="Create Checklist"
        categoryId="CheckList.commands.category"
        id="CheckList.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension       
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
        commandId="CheckList.commands.sampleCommand"
        class="checklist.handlers.createChecklistHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
        commandId="CheckList.commands.sampleCommand"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        sequence="M1+8"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
           label="Create Checklist"
           mnemonic="M"
           id="CheckList.menus.sampleMenu">
            <command
              commandId="CheckList.commands.sampleCommand"
              mnemonic="C"
              id="CheckList.menus.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
           id="CheckList.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
              commandId="CheckList.commands.sampleCommand"
              icon="icons/sample.gif"
              tooltip="Create migration Checklist"
              id="CheckList.toolbars.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you used another plugin name that the one already installed ?

Comment: @scawf no.. i used different names

Comment: You should try using different id for the menu

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the new menu is in a plug-in that *is* in the launch configuration, but *not* in the product definition.

*EDIT*:

I expect that your current product definition is plug-in based rather than feature based:

[image: Overview oage]

You can now add the wanted plug-ins via the Dependencies page:

[image: Dependencies page]

Comment: i think this might be the issue. Any help on knowing the product definition